# Reading from a web directory instead of single url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have a python script I'm using to parse html elements from a url, with the aid of Beautiful Soup.

I now want to parse all html files in the directory, rather than picking every file and executing one by one. After a weekend of working through modifying my script, I have hit a brick wall!

I have played around with `os.walk` to help me but I am struggling to integrate with my current script. I'm thinking there should be way to simply write a loop and change my input from a file to a directory? But that does that mean that I can no longer use `urllib` because my url is now a file list?

This is the start of my script. All the parsed elements in each file in the directory are identical, so nothing else should need to be changed.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/src_files/abc1.html'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
```

Expected results should be as if I ran my current script on each html file in the directory individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't need `urllib` anymore, since you want to parse saved HTML files in a directory (not fetching HTML pages from remote HTTP server).

To find all HTML files in a directory you need to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html#module-glob) module.

**Example:**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from glob import glob

# returns list of all .html files in directory.
htmlFilesList = glob('./*.html') 

for i, htmlFile in enumerate(htmlFilesList):
    saved_html = open(htmlFile, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(saved_html, 'html.parser')

    # Close opened file
    saved_html.close()
```